# How to use httpget on AdobeAIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, http-get, home-automation

Using some home automation software that allows me to use httpget/httppost to get the status and control the state of devices in my home. I can use it just fine when I'm on my home wifi network (using the internal IP address in the URL), but when I attempt the same outside of my network, nothing happens. I have all ports forwarded properly, because if I post the exact same URL into my browser, it will perform whatever task was indicated.

An example would be:

```
function LampOn(event:MouseEvent):void{
import flash.net.*;
var url:String = "http://" + ipaddy + "/HomeSeer_REST_API.aspx?function=setdevicebyname&param1=lamp&param2=on";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
}
```

When I use my home IP in the variable 'ipaddy' it works fine, when I use my external IP (in the form username:password@ipaddress:port ) it does nothing.

Comment: add event listeners to the loader (for complete,ioerror and securityerror then update your answer, you can also monitor your traffic to check what is happening

Comment: likely not a programming issue, but a network setup issue.